# How to connect View and ViewModel using MVVMCross for Windows Phone Universal Platform?

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I have a pcl dll (Xamarin) and all the viewmodels, models, services, interfaces, converters are on this project.

I am already using this core on Android and IOS and now will start the Windows Phone app.

My main question for now is, how do I make a viewmodel the datacontext for a view. For sample: LoginViewModel.cs (core) and LoginView.xaml...

I am using MVVMCross and The Windows Phone project is 8.1

Than you in advance.

Updating:

I tried this:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="Tocalivros.WindowsPhone.Views.LoginView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Tocalivros.WindowsPhone.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


public sealed partial class LoginView : MvxWindowsPage<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
```

But now I get this error: "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0263  Partial declarations of 'LoginView' must not specify different base classes"

Based on samples, I tried a different aproach, instead of making the view of type view model, I create a ViewModel as a property and set it as DataContext for the view. 
Like this:

public sealed partial class LoginView : MvxWindowsPage
    {
            public new LoginViewModel ViewModel
            {
                get { return (LoginViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
                set { base.ViewModel = value; }
            }

```
        public LoginView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
```

But this way the viewmodel wont be initiated with the required parameters... (IServices)

It makes me think the better aproach is the first:

```
public sealed partial class LoginView : MvxWindowsPage<LoginViewModel> but I get error...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like with every other platform in MvvmCross.

```
public class LoginPage : MvxWindowsPage<LoginViewModel>
{
}
```

Inside your view you will see something like this:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="somenamspace.Views.LoginPage">
<!-- Put your layout here -->
</views:MvxWindowsPage>
```

The datacontext is now done for that view.

Comment: Hi Martijn, but once I change the view.cs partial class to: public sealed partial class LoginView : MvxWindowsPage<LoginViewModel> I get this error: "Partial declarations of 'LoginView' must not specify different base classes"

Comment: So did you change the xaml view also to that same base class? They both need to be of the type MvxWindowsPage. You can see that here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/nuspec/WCommonContent/FirstView.xaml.pp

Comment: Yes, I did...:  <views:MvxWindowsPage